# Blowfish Cipher Behavior doesn't work in Cakephp 2+

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, encryption, blowfish

The Cipher Behavior on [The Bakery](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/xemle/2008/08/26/cipher-behavior) doesn't work after updating to Cakephp 2+.  Receiving the error ***Fatal error: Call to undefined function getmicrotime()*** anytime the behavior is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 139 of the behavior, getMicrotime() is called. `srand(getMicrotime()*1000);`
`getMicrotime()` was removed from [Cakephp 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html).

Just change `getMicrotime()` to `microtime(true)` and the behavior will work normally.

Answer (score 2):

Latest stable 2.x already provides blowfish encryption using `Security::hash()` so use that instead.

Comment: 2.x allows the use of blowfish encryption, however the behavior from The Bakery listed above had some additional functionality like auto-decrypt that made it useful.  Rather than rewriting the behavior with the additional needed functionality myself it was easier just to change the lines mentioned and continue using the behavior.  Unless there is some new behavior or included cake functionality that does these things?